# Hot to sum up files in folder structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the given array:

```
Array (7812)
0 {foldername: "", amount_of_files: 12, children: 86}
1 {foldername: "/pm", amount_of_files: 3, children: 7}
2 {foldername: "/pm/css", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0}
3 {foldername: "/pm/js", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0}
4 {foldername: "/stohg", amount_of_files: 1, children: 2}
5 {foldername: "/stohg/de", amount_of_files: 6, children: 1}
6 {foldername: "/stohg/de/pictures", amount_of_files: 21, children: 1}
...
```

and I want to sum up all files to the first level:

```
1 {foldername: "/pm", all_files: 5}
2 {foldername: "/stohg", all_files: 28}
...
```

I think part of the solution is:

```
array.filter(e => {
  const folders = e.foldername.split("/");
  if (folders.length === 1) {
    //maybe something with folders.reduce(); ?
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple regex and can do this in a single reduce method. Here we are checking for the pattern `/<word>`.

```js
var regEx = new RegExp(/^\/\w+$/, 'gm');

var folders = [{foldername: "", amount_of_files: 12, children: 86},
{foldername: "/pm", amount_of_files: 3, children: 7},
{foldername: "/pm/css", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0},
{foldername: "/pm/js", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0},
{foldername: "/stohg", amount_of_files: 1, children: 2},
{foldername: "/stohg/de", amount_of_files: 6, children: 1},
{foldername: "/stohg/de/pictures", amount_of_files: 21, children: 1}];

var sum = folders.reduce((acc, folder) => {
  if (regEx.test(folder.foldername)) {
    acc += folder.amount_of_files;
  }
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This is just giving me a number. A need the number of `/pm`, `/stohg` and every first level folder that is following, each. The expected result is giving in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just split by the slash and group them together before summing .amount_of_files up
Output formatted slightly different from what you mentioned in your posts, but result is the same

```
<script>
function get_root_folder_path(path) {
    if( path === "" )
    return "/"; 
    var names = path.split("/");
  console.log(names);
    if( names.length >= 1 ) return "/" + names[1]; //note: names[0] === ""
  else return "INVALI3D";
}

var objs = [
{foldername: "", amount_of_files: 12, children: 86},
{foldername: "/pm", amount_of_files: 3, children: 7},
{foldername: "/pm/css", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0},
{foldername: "/pm/js", amount_of_files: 1, children: 0},
{foldername: "/stohg", amount_of_files: 1, children: 2},
{foldername: "/stohg/de", amount_of_files: 6, children: 1},
{foldername: "/stohg/de/pictures", amount_of_files: 21, children: 1},
];


// create an object to store your new root folder data
var root_folders = {};

for(var i = 0;i < objs.length;i ++) {
    var root_folder_path = get_root_folder_path(objs[i].foldername);
  if( root_folders[root_folder_path] === undefined )
    root_folders[root_folder_path] = {amount_of_files: objs[i].amount_of_files};
  else
    root_folders[root_folder_path].amount_of_files += objs[i].amount_of_files;
}

console.log(root_folders);

</script>
```

Outputs :

```
{
  /: {
    amount_of_files: 12
  },
  /pm: {
    amount_of_files: 5
  },
  /stohg: {
    amount_of_files: 28
  }
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3f7kgLvq/

Comment: This is working, but how do I need to modify the code to fit the required output. An Array of Objets with two keys: foldername and amount_of_files?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved on my own and I want to provide the solution to help someone else that finds my post.

```js
array.forEach(e => {
      const folders = e.foldername.split("/");
      const isRoot = folders.length === 2;
      if (isRoot) {
        result.push(e);
      } else {
        result.forEach((elem, index) => {
          if (elem.foldername === "/" + folders[1]) {
            result[index] = {...result[index], amount_of_files: elem.amount_of_files + e.amount_of_files}
          }
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
```